# Eliminar elementos en dos listas en base al valor que tiene el elemento en esa posición en una de ellas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy creando un programa que me carga unos datos en dos listas, `diámetro` y `altura`, y tengo que eliminar los datos de ambas listas cuando la segunda lista, `altura`,  tiene el valor 0.

Este es el código:

```
a=0
for i in diametro:
    for j in altura:
        if a == 0:
            diametro.pop(a)
            altura.pop(a)
     print(diámetro, altura)
     a=a+1
```

Y me arroja un error en `if a == 0`, dice:

> List index out of range

No se porqué me aparece este error.

Comment: Hola Lyan Rocio Mosquera Garcia, bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: podrías pegar más código, por lo menos donde aparecen las listas diametro y altura, además de pegar una screenshot del error.

Comment: Lyan te he contestado pero deberías aclarar dos cosas, primero de todo es imposible que tengas ese error a no ser que tengas una lista vacía con tu código. Creo que al crear la pregunta tuviste varios errores tipográficos (como los `For` en mayúsculas) y que `if a == 0:` es en realidad `if j == 0:`,  esto si que ocasiona un error de indexado al aplicar `pop`. Lo otro que deberías especificar aunque se puede intuir es si ambas listas tienen el mismo número de elementos. De todas formas el gran "pecado" es eliminar elementos mientras iteras con un `for in`.

Answer (score 1):

Se deduce que tienes dos listas con el mismo número de elementos y quieres eliminar los elementos en una posición determinada en ambas listas cuando en `altura` el valor en esa posición es 0. El primer error en este caso es que debes recorrer las listas a la par, no dos `for` anidados (la segunda lista se recorre al completo por cada elemento de la primera).

Además, hay que tener dos cosas en cuenta si pretendes hacer la eliminación *in-place*:

- **Nunca** se debe modificar la longitud de una lista o cualquier otro iterable (ni agregar ni añadir elementos) cuando se itera con un `for in`.
- Es obvio, pero hay que tener en cuenta que **cuando se elimina un elemento de la lista, los índices de los elementos posteriores a él pasan a ser una unidad menos**, por lo que hay que tenerlo en cuenta. Si usamos el típico `for i in range(len(lista))` hay que tener en cuanta que la longitud de la lista va a cambiar, indices que antes eran válidos en el momento que eliminamos un elemento ya no lo son.

Dicho esto, podemos hacer lo que deseas modificando las listas o creando nuevos objetos:

- **In-place:**

  Una posible solución es iterar sobre altura y crear una lista que almacene los índices de los elementos que son 0. Luego usamos un `for` para iterar sobre ella y con `del` eliminar estos indices de ambas listas. Hay que corregir los índices para tener en cuenta el segundo punto anterior:

  ```
  # Metodo 1
  filtro = [i-n for i, n in enumerate((i for i, a in enumerate(altura) if not a))]

  for i in filtro:
      del diametro[i]
      del altura[i]
  ```

  La parte `i-n for i, n in enumerate` de la lista por compresión se encarga de corregir el índice restando a cada indice el numero de elementos previamente eliminados cuando se llega a el, sería equivalente a :

  ```
  # Metodo 2
  filtro = [i for i, a in enumerate(altura) if not a]

  e = 0
  for i in filtro:
      del diametro[i-e]
      del altura[i-e]
      e += 1
  ```

  Otra posibilidad es usar `range + len` para generar los índices pero iterando de derecha a izquierda:

  ```
  # Metodo 3
  for i in range(len(altura) - 1, -1, -1):
      if not altura[i]:
          del altura[i]
          del diametro[i]
  ```
- **Creando dos nuevas listas:**

  ```
  # Metodo 4
  filtro = [i for i, a in enumerate(altura) if a]
  diametro = [diametro[i] for i in filtro]
  altura = [altura[i] for i in filtro]
  ```

  Una opción distinta es usar `zip`, aunque es algo menos idiomática:

  ```
  # Metodo 5
  diametro, altura = (list(l) for l in zip(*((d, a)
                              for d, a in zip(diametro, altura) if a)))
  ```

  Por último, la opción más eficiente que se me ocurre es usar una máscara boleana, al estilo NumPy. Podemos usar [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) para aplicarla:

  ```
  # Metodo 6 
  import itertools

  filtro_boleano = [a != 0 for a in altura]
  diametro = list(itertools.compress(diametro, filtro_boleano))
  altura = list(itertools.compress(altura, filtro_boleano))
  ```

> **Nota:** `list.pop` elimina y **retorna** el elemento situado en el índice que se le pasa. Si no vas a usar el valor eliminado es mejor usar `del` para tales fines.

En todos los casos para por ejemplo:

```
diametro = [4, 8, 7, 2, 3, 6, 5, 9, 6, 8] 
altura   = [0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 3, 4, 8, 0]
```

Obtenemos:

> [7, 3, 5, 9, 6]
>   [6, 1, 3, 4, 8]

---

**IMPORTANTE**

**Remover un elemento de una lista es una operación costosa** por lo general ya que implica reacomodar el resto de los elementos (al igual que ocurre con `list.insert`). Si no tenemos problemas de memoria y priorizamos el tiempo de ejecución, puede ser importante  optar por crear listas nuevas en vez de remover los items directamente, especialmente si creamos las lista mediante compresión. Llevando esto al extremo, para listas de un millón de elementos, con la eliminación del 50% de los items tenemos los siguentes tiempos de ejecución como referencia para los métodos mostrados arriba en el mismo orden:

> Método 1: 97.64361238479614 segundos
>
> Método 2: 304.90778708457947 segundos    !!!!
>
> Método 3: 98.10549569129944 segundos
>
> **Método 4: 0.1168980598449707 segundos**
>
> Método 5: 0.34819936752319336 segundos
>
> **Método 6: 0.0786902904510498 segundos**

La diferencia es abismal y muestra como el mejor método de todos es el 6 en cuanto a tiempo de ejecución seguido de cerca por el 4, a costa de usar mucha más memoria.

Answer (score 0):

Espero que estés bien

La clave está en cómo armas tu ciclo for, la función `range()` y `len()` te serán de mucha ayuda para recorrer listas usando un ciclo de iteración

```
for i in range(len(diametro)):
  for i in range(len(altura)):
    if altura[i] == 0:
       diametro.pop(i)
       altura.pop(i)
print(diametro, altura)
```

Si en la posición i de tu lista altura encuentras un dato con valor igual a 0, esa posición se eliminará tanto de la lista diámetro como de la lista altura.

Espero que te haya servido mi ayuda, encontrarás una mejor explicación sobre las funciones `range()` y `len()` [aquí](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/) y [aquí](http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/archive/python/spanish2e/cap07.html).

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes tener en cuenta que la función ***pop*** solo sirve con listas, en tu código esta la variable ***a*** que es un numero o **int** por lo que no puede aplicarle esta función, ahora con esto claro podemos cambiar el código de la siguiente forma:

```
for i in range(len(diametro)): 
       for j in range(len(altura)): 
              if altura[j] == 0:          
                  diametro.pop(j)       
                  altura.pop(j)    
       print(diametro, altura)
```

Ahora si se sale de rango en tu código solo ahi una posibilidad, que cuando le hagas ***diámetro.pop(a)*** la lista este vacía, en caso contrario es imposible que marque un error de estos.

Existe otra alternativa con tu código y es que tu deseas eliminar cuando **altura** tiene un cero, si deseas eliminar el elemento de la lista **altura** y de la lista **distancia**( que es posible que no contenga este numero ) solo hace falta ponerlo con la variable **j** y nada mas, porque **j** es la variable que va recorriendo la lista evitando  que se salga de rango, a menos que las 2 listas sean de diferente longitud, entonces el código quedaría así:

```
for i in range(len(diametro)): 
           for j in range(len(altura)): 
                  if altura[j] == 0:          
                     diametro.pop(j)       
                     altura.pop(j)    
           print(diametro, altura)
```

Con esto te garantizas de eliminar el elemento en la lista altura, y si deseas eliminar el cero de la lista diámetro tendrías que agregarle un **if** que diga lo mismo que el primer **if** pero con diámetro, es decir:

```
for i in range(len(diametro)): 
           for j in range(len(altura)): 
                  if diametro[j]==0:          
                     diametro.pop(a)  
                 if altura[j]==0:   
                      altura.pop(a)  
           print(diametro, altura)
```

> Ten presente que no es necesario hacer una variable externa para saber el indice donde debo eliminar un elemento, la función *range* ya lo hace por ti.